# How to get clientAccessToken from API key in Dialogflow V2

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I have used API.AI Android SDK in one of my application, it was using clientAccessToken for dialogflow. Now dialogflow has migrated from v2 and clientAccessToken is deprecated. So is there any way to get clientAccessToken from API key now.

I have used below code.

```
private AIService aiService;
final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration(clientAccessTokenAI,
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
    aiService = AIService.getService(context, config);
    aiService.setListener(this);
    aiService.startListening();
```

Is there any other way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The Dialogflow client library and Dialogflow API V1 have been deprecated and were shut down on October 23th, 2019 - so even if you were able to mint a new `clientAccessToken`, your implementation would not work.

To continue using Dialogflow using the V2 API, then you can leverage Google's [Java Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/libraries/java) (please see the [quickstart guide for Java](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api#detect-intent-text-java)).

The downside is that you will have to re-implement whatever API.AI gave you out of the box (if needed). On the upside, the V2 API is significantly easier to interact with, around the central idea of the Detect Intent request.